# What is $\rm cl([-2,2]\times[-3,3])$ in this topology

Tags: general-topology

I have this topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $$\sigma=\{\emptyset\}\cup\big\{\bigcup_{r\in A} \Omega_r:~A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^+\big\}$$

where $$\Omega_{r}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=r^2\}$$

I want to find $\rm cl(A)$ where $A=[-2,2]\times[-3,3]$

Is $$\rm cl(A)=\Omega_{\sqrt{13}}$$ or $$\rm cl(A)=\bigcup_{0\leq r\leq \sqrt{13}}\Omega_r$$

Thank you very much

Comment: In the definition of $\sigma$, the real number $r$ is not included in $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. Here $A$ has no meaning.

Comment: If each circle centered at origin with radius $r$ is open in your topology $\sigma$, your second answer is right.

Comment: Set builder notation uses a colon.  It does not use a comma.  If r in A subset R×R, then r is not a real number, contrarily to your useage of r.

Comment: It is clear that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: Note that the first answer is clearly false since it even does not contain $A$.